# Apache Shiro, INI-Configuration, Perms per URL: How to get URL params?

Tags: jsf, authorization, shiro

I want to use [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org) in my JSF-Application to perform URL-based authorization checks, configuration done in shiro.ini As I see in the [Shiro-documentation](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-webini) there is a way to use a "perms"-filter

```
/remoting/rpc/** = authc, perms["remote:invoke"]
```

In my scenario I want this functionality, but on entity-level[1](https://shiro.apache.org), where the entity-Id is in the http-request

```
# "Open settings for user with id=123":
# /user/settings.xhtml?user_id=123
/user/settings.xhtml = perms["user:update:XXX"]
```

So, how do I do this with Shiro? How to I tell the perms-filter to check for http-params? Or is this supposed to be done in my Realm-Implemenation, concrete by calling FacesContext?

[1](https://shiro.apache.org) This can be done at least programmatically:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("printer:query:lp7200")
```

https://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is possible](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/hundreds-of-url-and-perms-relationship-management-tp7526644p7527823.html) to do this by implementing and using own "org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter" subclasses in the software. This own classes can be declared in the shiro.ini:

```
[main]
user = filter.FooFilter
```

The AccessControlFilter-class provides an "isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue)"-method, which can be overridden to use "request.getParameterMap()" for getting the HTTP-GET-parameters.

As an example, you could have a look at my project [tiramisu](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/tiramisu) (quite outdated).
See [CompanyManagerPermissionsFilter](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/tiramisu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bestellbaer/filter/CompanyManagerPermissionsFilter.java) (which extends [CompanyScopedPermissionsFilter](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/tiramisu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bestellbaer/filter/CompanyScopedPermissionsFilter.java), which extends [DomainPermissionsFilter](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/tiramisu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bestellbaer/filter/DomainPermissionsFilter.java)), included in [WEB-INF/shiro.ini](https://github.com/SchulteMarkus/tiramisu/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/shiro.ini).